# В словаре Аванесова есть ошибки?

Tags: типы-ошибок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка](http://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0571.htm)

(Вопрос не пропускается из-за нехватки печатных символов, поэтому пришлось что-то написать.)

Comment: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.56

Comment: @Серж: спасибо, Серж! Только там не говорится об окончании -ит. Кстати, "матершинник" там так пишется (через Ш). Интересно, почему? Я недавно пришёл к выводу, что оно произносится через Ш, а пишется через Щ.

Comment: Интересные объяснения по поводу возникновения форм **сыпать — сыплю — сыпит — сыпят** дает Н. Еськова ("Избранные работы по русистике"). https://books.google.ee/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=aJFhbPV9ZA&sig=ACfU3U3snMoeq9kR0daBVHeHf4ZHj6SCDw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZxuXNwuXmAhXKAhAIHT3HAFMQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false

Comment: _Артём Луговой: В словаре Аванесова есть ошибки? <...> сыпит, сыпят, см. § 29_ === Аванесов же написал: **см. § 29**.

Comment: А где этот параграф?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: А где этот параграф?_ === В том же словаре, что и статья "сыпать", на которую Вы сослались.

Comment: § 29 на [Стр.698](http://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0698.htm)

Comment: *Спасибо, tum_!*

Comment: @Артем Луговой, вы это слово в той статье видели? Я не видел.

Comment: @Серж, вы меня совсем запутали! :) Какое слово?

Comment: @Артем Луговой, я не внимательно прочитал ваш вопрос. Я думал, вы имеете виду варианты сыпЕшь наряду с сыплЕшь. Поэтому привел ссылку.

Comment: А второй раз я имел в виду слово "матершина".

Comment: @Серж, да, там слова в конце: *Так что из уст матершинника...*

Answer (score 2):

Какой-то архаизм, о котором ещё иногда упоминают ([на Грамоте](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273600), например).

**Вопрос № 273600**

> Пожалуйста, помогите определить спряжение глагола: мы сыпЕМ или мы сыпИМ? от какого инфинитива образована эта форма? К одному или к
>   разным инфинитивам относятся формы они сыпЯТ и они сыплЮТ?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Глагол сыпать (инфинитив только такой) имеет вариантные личные формы: сыплет, сыплем, сыплют (эти формы являются строго нормативными)
>   и сыпет, сыпем, сыпят (встречаются в разговорной речи, но проникают и
>   в письменную речь). Это уникальный глагол: у него есть две
>   параллельные системы форм настоящего времени – с окончаниями первого
>   спряжения (сыплешь, сыплет, сыплем, сыплете, сыплют) и с окончаниями
>   второго спряжения (**сыпишь, сыпит, сыпим, сыпите, сыпят**). О том, что
>   эта вторая система форм имеет окончания именно второго спряжения,
>   писал, например, великий русский языковед А. А. Шахматов: «Вместо
>   сыплю – сыплешь весьма обычно сыплю – сыпишь». Но на письме сложилась
>   последовательная передача с окончаниями второго спряжения только одной
>   формы – это форма 3-го лица мн. числа: сыпят.  Остальные формы второй
>   группы со временем стали писаться с окончаниями первого спряжения:
>   сыпет, сыпем.

Comment: Очень интересно, спасибо!